# Button inside modalpopup doesn't execute a line of code for outside component

Tags: c#, asp.net, popup

Problems encountered:

- Button inside UpdatePanel, which is inside ModalPopup, won't execute
  `.DataBind()`
- Button executes other codes but not `.DataBind()`

What I want to work:

- When the button in the ModalPopup is clicked, `.DataBind()` is executed, Button is inside an UdatePanel and Gridview is outside the UpdatPanel

I have three updatepanels, all just to execute `ModalPopupExtender` separately based on some conditions. I also have a gridview, with a custom button to open the first popup, which is outside of the three updatepanels. Two updatepanels has a button for executing the `.DataBind()` for the gridview and at the same time hiding the other popups. After the buttonclick inside the popup (this is also inside an updatepanel), the previous popup closes which means that it executes the code `.Hide()` in codebehind, but the  `.DataBind()` did not even though I put `.DataBind()` before `.Hide()`

I also tried to refresh the page using `Response.Redirect` and `ServerTransfer` instead of using `.DataBind()`, and the button stopped working.
I also tried to surround the gridview inside another updatepanel so I could just use `.Update` but when I execute the button for the popup, it refuses to close and the second popup appeared making it look like nested popups, the button for the second popup also stopped working.

The code works fine but the only thing that doesn't work is to refresh the gridview after the buttonclick inside the popup. If I click the button for the popup again (custom button inside the gridview), then that's when the gridview updates, and that is wrong.

I ran out of ideas how to work around this, any suggestions for this??

HTML

```
     <asp:GridView ID="gridview" runat="server" CssClass="table table-hover" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="OutgoingID" DataSourceID="SqlDataMaterials" HorizontalAlign="Center" OnRowCommand="gridview_RowCommand" Width="100%">
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="#">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Button ID="myButton" runat="server" Text="View" CommandName="ClickMe" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("OutgoingID") %>' CausesValidation="False" />
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ClassificationName" HeaderText="ClassificationName" SortExpression="ClassificationName" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="MaterialName" HeaderText="MaterialName" SortExpression="MaterialName" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Qty" HeaderText="Qty" SortExpression="Qty" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Total" HeaderText="Total" SortExpression="Total" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="RequestDate" HeaderText="RequestDate" SortExpression="RequestDate" />
                                </Columns>
                                <EmptyDataTemplate>
                                    <asp:Panel ID="Panel3" runat="server" CssClass="breadcrumb">
                                        No Requests for this project.
                                    </asp:Panel>
                                </EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:GridView>
```

first popup

```
         <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Height="400" Width="700" class="modalPopup">
                        <section class=" text-center" style="height: 149px; padding: 2px; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;">
                            <section class="label-info">
                                <asp:Button ID="btn_Close" runat="server" Text="Close" Width="50px" Height="20px" CssClass="btn-danger pull-right" Font-Size="Smaller" />



         <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="REQUEST INFORMATION" CssClass="label">

                            </asp:Label>

                        </section>
                        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                (Some very long html here with buttons that execute the other popups)
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
                    </section>
                </asp:Panel>
  <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
            <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" BehaviorID="popup" PopupControlID="Panel2" DropShadow="True" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" TargetControlID="HiddenField1" OkControlID="btn_Close">
                <Animations>
 <OnShown><Fadein Duration="0.50" /></OnShown>
 <OnHiding><Fadeout Duration=".05" /></OnHiding>
                </Animations>
            </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
```

second popup

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField2" runat="server" />
            <asp:Panel ID="panelSuccess" runat="server" Height="150" Width="300" class="modalPopup">
                <section class="text-center">
                    <h5>Request successfully approved.</h5>
                    <br />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSuccessOk" runat="server" Text="OK" CssClass="btn btn-sm btn-success" OnClick="btnSuccessOk_Click" />

                </section>
            </asp:Panel>
            <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalAlertSuccess" runat="server" BehaviorID="popup2" PopupControlID="panelSuccess" DropShadow="True" TargetControlID="HiddenField2" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" OkControlID="btnSuccessOk">
                <Animations>
                             <OnShown><Fadein Duration="0.50" /></OnShown>
                             <OnHiding><Fadeout Duration=".05" /></OnHiding>
                </Animations>
            </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSuccessOk" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

third popup

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>

            <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField3" runat="server" />
            <asp:Panel ID="panelCancel" runat="server" Height="150" Width="300" class="modalPopup">
                <section class="text-center">
                    <h5>Request Cancelled.</h5>
                    <br />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnCancelRq" runat="server" Text="OK" CssClass="btn btn-sm btn-success" OnClick="btnCancelRq_Click" />

                </section>
            </asp:Panel>
            <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalAlertCancel" runat="server" BehaviorID="popup3" PopupControlID="panelCancel" DropShadow="True" TargetControlID="HiddenField3" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" OkControlID="btnCancelRq">
                <Animations>
                             <OnShown><Fadein Duration="0.50" /></OnShown>
                             <OnHiding><Fadeout Duration=".05" /></OnHiding>
                </Animations>
            </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>

        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

AND THE THE CODE BEHIND

this is from the first popup

```
protected void btn_approve_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (hf_outgoingId.Value != null)
                {
                    var abc = (from a in db.Outgoings
                               where a.OutgoingID == Convert.ToInt32(hf_outgoingId.Value)
                               select a).FirstOrDefault();
                    abc.Status = "APPROVED";
                    db.SubmitChanges();

                    gridview.DataBind();
                    ModalPopupExtender1.Hide();
                    ModalAlertSuccess.Show();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception x)
            {

            }


        }
```

and just in case the second/third popup

```
protected void btnSuccessOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gridview.DataBind();
}

protected void btnCancelRq_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gridview.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: specify only problem code..

Comment: @Asif.Ali yes i did, the last block of code is the main problem. the html is for how the code is executed especially since updatepanels are used, it would be confusing if I just put the the onclick command and then the question can be mistaken as a duplicate of 'gridview/button inside updatepanel not executing' and since what I am dealing is the opposite of it.

Comment: trigger it on javascript or in postbacktrigger in updatepanel.

Comment: @Asif.Ali I already have tried using postbacktrigger (also tried asyncpost) but it didn't work, as for javascript I am still looking for an answer without using updatepanel.

Comment: I think its very fewer chance to get correct and accurate answer you have to edit your post and make sure specific to your exact problem.

Comment: @Asif.Ali I have an answer now, I put a trigger in the main popup, I didn't try this before since I was thinking the problem is with the last two popups. But I still don't know why the two popups wont fire after buttonclick, I also edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign data source before databind to gridview to bind data

```
protected void btnSuccessOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gridview.DataSourceID = SqlDataMaterials;
    gridview.DataBind();
}

protected void btnCancelRq_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     gridview.DataSourceID = SqlDataMaterials;
     gridview.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a working code now, but it still didn't answer why the button won't fire in the last two popups, Instead of putting the trigger in the last two `modalpopupextender`, I put it in the main popup, which their button is still inside an update panel. I don't know what the deal is with the last two popups why it won't execute since all of them are inside an updatepanel.

But I think that the buttonclick worked is because my main popup has the updatepanel inside it's panel, while the other two is surrounded within an updatepanel.

```
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Height="400" Width="700" class="modalPopup" Style="display: none;">
<section class=" text-center" style="height: 149px; padding: 2px; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;">
                    <section class="label-info">
                        <asp:Button ID="btn_Close" runat="server" Text="Close" Width="50px" Height="20px" CssClass="btn-danger pull-right" Font-Size="Smaller" />

                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="REQUEST INFORMATION" CssClass="label">

                        </asp:Label>

                    </section>
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" >
                        <ContentTemplate>
        (some long html code with button 'btn_approve')
                                </ContentTemplate>
                                <Triggers>
                                    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btn_approve" />
                                </Triggers>
                            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code behind

```
protected void btn_approve_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (hf_outgoingId.Value != null)
                {
                    var abc = (from a in db.Outgoings
                               where a.OutgoingID == Convert.ToInt32(hf_outgoingId.Value)
                               select a).FirstOrDefault();
                    abc.Status = "APPROVED";
                    db.SubmitChanges();

                    gridview.DataBind();
                    ModalPopupExtender1.Hide();
                    ModalAlertSuccess.Show();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception x)
            {

            }


        }
```

I can also show the second popup right after I click the button without making it look like nested popups.